# Why running a Laravel 9 test is deleting my database?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, laravel-9

I am usgin Laravel 9 test tool.
I dropped the database, recreated and imported using SQL statement.
With all the database set, I used the browser to log in with my user, and everything worded just fine.

Then I ran the `php artisan test --filter HomeControllerTest` and all the database was deleted! HOW COME?????

here is the test code:

```
<?php
namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class HomeControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_home_view_requires_authentication()
    {
        
        // Log in as the created user and try to access the home page
        $response = $this->postJson('/login', [
            'email' => 'test@example.com',
            'password' => 'password',
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(302);
        $response->assertRedirect(route('home'));

        $response = $this->get(route('home'));
        $response->assertOk();
        $response->assertViewIs('home');
        $response->assertViewHasAll(['corretora', 'propostas']);
    }


    /**
     * Test if home page can be accessed by a guest user.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_home_view_requires_guest()
    {
        $response = $this->get(route('home'));

        $response->assertStatus(302);
        $response->assertRedirect(route('login'));
    }
}
```

Why my database was deleted? i do have a backup, of course, but should test do it?

Answer (score 0):

There was not an error. The use of the `use RefreshDatabase;` do the erasing.
I remove it and now is working good.